# quality gate . How to compare two releases

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to know if it is possible to add a condition in a Quality gate to compare two releases.

e.g. A condition to check if a release has decreades a 5% the number of "Critical issues" respect to the prvious one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to compare work that's currently being done against the previous release is to use the Leak Period and fill your quality gate with conditions "on New Code".

However, everything that's built in around the leak period and new code is focused on not adding new problems, rather than eliminating old problems. The thinking is that if you clean up the code you're working on anyway, old problems will gradually be eliminated organically.